# Why does my systemd timer only trigger once when the unit is a target?

Tags: systemd, systemd-timers

I have a couple of services (static site generators) that I want to trigger on a regular basis from the same systemd timer. I found [this question/answer](https://serverfault.com/a/966588/336913), which covers exactly what I want to do, and describes a setup whereby a `.target` file that `Wants=` multiple services is triggered by a corresponding timer. This sounds great, but I'm finding that when I actually set this up, it only ever triggers *once*, then disables itself!

I've prepared a minimal working example (this doesn't trigger multiple services, but demonstrates the same problem):

**`test-timer.timer`**:

```
[Unit]
Description=A test timer

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*-*-* *:*:30
Unit=test-timer.target

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

**`test-timer.target`**:

```
[Unit]
Description=Target unit
Wants=test-timer.service
After=test-timer.service

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

**`test-timer.service`**:

```
[Unit]
Description=Run test

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c "date --rfc-3339='seconds' >> /tmp/test-timer-output"

[Install]
Also=test-timer.target
```

Enable the timer:

```
$ sudo cp test-timer.* /etc/systemd/system/
$ sudo systemctl enable --now test-timer.timer
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/timers.target.wants/test-timer.timer → /etc/systemd/system/test-timer.timer.
```

Then, when I look at the output of `systemctl list-timers --all`, prior to the first run I get (ignoring other timers):

```
NEXT                        LEFT       LAST     PASSED       UNIT                ACTIVATES
Fri 2021-10-08 10:38:30 EDT 21s left   n/a      n/a          test-timer.timer    test-timer.target
```

After the first run, `NEXT` and `LEFT` have been replaced with `n/a`:

```
NEXT     LEFT    LAST                        PASSED        UNIT                  ACTIVATES
n/a      n/a     Fri 2021-10-08 10:38:32 EDT 1min 5s ago   test-timer.timer      test-timer.target
```

I've also tried adding `Persistent=true` to the `test-timer.target` and explicitly enabling `test-timer.target`, but neither of these work. Any time I do `systemctl restart test-timer.timer`, it restarts, but only triggers one run, then never has another go.

If I remove the layer of indirection by changing the `Unit=` line of `test-timer.timer` to `Unit=test-timer.service`, the service happily triggers itself every minute as expected.

Am I missing some configuration or installation step?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After getting some help on Twitter, I've managed to solve this issue. The problem is that a systemd *timer* will only activate services that are inactive, and the default behavior for a *target* is to activate and stay active unless something makes it go down (it is not tied to lifetime of the units it `Wants=`). To force the target unit to become inactive if *any* of the services it activates becomes inactive, use `BindsTo=` in place of `Wants=` in my example above. So, for this minimal example:

**`test-timer.target`**:

```
[Unit]
Description=Target unit
BindsTo=test-timer.service
After=test-timer.service

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

**`test-timer.service`**:

```
[Unit]
Description=Run test

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c "date --rfc-3339='seconds' >> /tmp/test-timer-output"

[Install]
Also=test-timer.target
```

You can then see that as soon as `test-timer.service` is finished running, `test-timer.target` will also become `inactive` (and thus the timer will be able to activate it again):

```
$ sudo systemctl list-units --all test-timer.target test-timer.service
  UNIT               LOAD   ACTIVE   SUB  DESCRIPTION
  test-timer.service loaded inactive dead Run test   
  test-timer.target  loaded inactive dead Target unit
```

Whereas prior to the change, the target was staying active after the service died:

```
$ sudo systemctl list-units --all test-timer.target test-timer.service
  UNIT               LOAD   ACTIVE   SUB    DESCRIPTION
  test-timer.service loaded inactive dead   Run test   
  test-timer.target  loaded active   active Target unit
```

Comment: Dagnabbit, you found the solution before I could post it :-)

Comment: Especially when you have multiple services triggered by a target and they are all oneshots, you may use `StopWhenUnneeded=True`. This will cause the target to become inactive after the work has been done.

Comment: Seems `StopWhenUnneeded=` works better than `BindsTo=`. With the latter, I got an error `xxx.target: Bound to unit yyy.service, but unit isn't active` whenever the target is activated.

Answer (score 3):

Using `BindsTo` has some disadvantages:

- A minor disadvantage is that you're defying the purpose of a target unit: Target units serve as well-known synchronization points and therefore must not contain any logic on their own (i.e. target units must not statically depend on any other units besides other target units). By statically adding dependencies to a target unit (`BindsTo` is a very strong dependency) you move part of a service unit's logic to said target unit, making it impossible to understand what a service unit does by just looking at the service unit. That's why service units must "register" themselves as dependency of target units using the `[Install]` section. However, due to this inversion of logic, you can no longer use `BindsTo` - because its inversion, `BoundBy`, can't be specified directly.
- Anyway, a more major disadvantage is that `BindsTo` enforces concurrency. Even though you mention only a single service unit, I assume that you're actually trying to start multiple service units by a single timer - otherwise the target unit would serve no purpose. If you'd attempt to bind multiple service unit to your target unit, all service units are equally required to run for the target unit to run. This means that all service units must start at the same time (i.e. enforced concurrency), and also means that if *any* of the specified service units stops, your target unit will stop, too. This might cause unexpected behaviour when the target is started again (either manually, or due to a timer) while some of the service units are still running.

To avoid these disadvantages I recommend the following:

1. Create the timer unit `test-timer.timer` that starts `test-timer.target`. Don't forget to enable the timer unit: `systemctl enable test-timer.timer`

   *`test-timer.timer`:*

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=A test timer

   [Timer]
   OnCalendar=*-*-* *:*:30
   Unit=test-timer.target

   [Install]
   WantedBy=timers.target
   ```
2. Create the mentioned `test-timer.target`. You won't need to specify the required service units here, the service units will rather "register" themselves as dependencies using `WantedBy`. Since we don't want the target unit to run indefinitely, we add `StopWhenUnneeded=true`. Systemd will then stop the target unit as soon as it served its purpose, i.e. when Systemd queued the service units to start.

   *`test-timer.target`:*

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=Target unit
   StopWhenUnneeded=true
   ```
3. Create your service units just the way you'd anyway. You can add `Wants`, `Requires`, `Before`, `After`, and all other (e.g. `Conflicts`) directives just as usual. Also add `WantedBy=test-timer.target`, allowing the service unit to "register" itself as requirement of the target unit when enabled. After enabling the service unit Systemd will start the service unit as soon as the target unit is started, i.e. when the timer triggers.

   However, due to `StopWhenUnneeded=true`, Systemd would stop the target unit as soon as the service unit was queued to start (i.e. immediately). This wouldn't hinder anyone (either manually, or due to a timer) to start the target unit again. Since the service units might still run, you might experience unexpected behaviour, just as with `BindsTo`. Thus we also add `Upholds=test-timer.target` and `After=test-timer.target`. These directives cause Systemd to ensure that the target unit runs while the service unit runs. It won't stop the target unit though; that's `StopWhenUnneeded=true`'s job. Together they effectively cause Systemd to keep the target unit running until *all* service units with `Upholds=test-timer.target` stop (`BindsTo` in contrast stops the target unit as soon as *any* service unit stops).

   In general I recommend using `Type=oneshot` services instead of the default `Type=simple` in the context of service units triggered by timers. That's because Systemd will consider a `Type=simple` service unit started immediately and dead when the command finished. With `Type=oneshot` Systemd will rather consider the service unit "starting" while the command runs and switch directly to dead after it has finished. This is a major difference for concurrency and `After`/`Before` directives: With `Type=simple` the command of a service unit won't wait for the command of another service unit that was declared to run `After` to finish. With `Type=oneshot` Systemd does wait.

   - Okay, now let's assume that we want to start two service units, `test-timer-1.service` and `test-timer-2.service`. They can run in parallel, but aren't required to. Systemd shall therefore trigger the timer unit, then start the target unit, and then both service units in parallel. The target unit shouldn't stop before both service units stopped, and so should the timer unit. To achieve this create the following two service units. Don't forget to enable the service units (`systemctl enable test-timer-1.service test-timer-2.service`).

     *`test-timer-1.service`:*

     ```
     [Unit]
     Description=Run test 1
     After=test-timer.target
     Upholds=test-timer.target

     [Service]
     Type=oneshot
     ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c "sleep 3 ; date --rfc-3339='seconds' >> /tmp/test-timer-output-1"

     [Install]
     WantedBy=test-timer.target
     ```

     *`test-timer-2.service`:*

     ```
     [Unit]
     Description=Run test 2
     After=test-timer.target
     Upholds=test-timer.target

     [Service]
     Type=oneshot
     ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c "sleep 3 ; date --rfc-3339='seconds' >> /tmp/test-timer-output-2"

     [Install]
     WantedBy=test-timer.target
     ```
   - If you rather want `test-timer-2.service` to start not before `test-timer-1.service` has finished, you simply add `After=test-timer-1.service` to `test-timer-2.service`. Systemd shall then trigger the timer unit, then start the target unit, and then just the first service unit. When the first service unit has finished, Systemd shall start the second service unit. Systemd shall stop the target unit as soon as all service units have finished (here: just the second service unit), also causing the timer unit to stop. This would be impossible with `BindsTo`. Again, don't forget to enable the service units.

     *`test-timer-1.service`:*

     ```
     [Unit]
     Description=Run test 1
     After=test-timer.target
     Upholds=test-timer.target

     [Service]
     Type=oneshot
     ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c "sleep 3 ; date --rfc-3339='seconds' >> /tmp/test-timer-output-1"

     [Install]
     WantedBy=test-timer.target
     ```

     *`test-timer-2.service`:*

     ```
     [Unit]
     Description=Run test 2
     After=test-timer.target test-timer-1.service
     Upholds=test-timer.target

     [Service]
     Type=oneshot
     ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c "sleep 3 ; date --rfc-3339='seconds' >> /tmp/test-timer-output-2"

     [Install]
     WantedBy=test-timer.target
     ```

I'm using this exact setup to orchestrate backups: I first run some service units to prepare the system for backup (e.g. create snapshots), then run the backups (some can run in parallel, some must run after another) and finally clean up.

Comment: Why do the services need to be enabled? My timers work fine without me having to enable the services.

Comment: That's because the timer isn't actually starting the services, but the target. The target in turn starts the services, what requires the services to be enabled first.